# Should we keep or delete completed jobs or pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I can get jobs and pods in kubernetes after they have been completed.Then I have 2 choices:
 1. delete them, but I can't find the history anymore, maybe I should build a history server by myself?
 2. keep them, I wonder if there is any performance problem when lots of pods and jobs accumulate
Which one is kubernetes designed to be? Or a third choice?